# Category listing filtered for taxonomy term in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am using a custom posttype "Business", a taxonomy "Region", and "Categories" to indicate the type of business. So, e.g.  Business: "Mamma Mia Pizzeria" /Region: "Rotterdam" /Category: "Pizzerias" (parent category: "Food").

Now, I'd like to create a number of listings:

(1) Show all Categories (unique listing - including parent) for a specific Region - only show a category if there is a Business attached to it, for the concerning region.

(2) Show all parent Categories (unique listing) for a specific Region - only show a parent category if there is a Business attached to it (via child category), for the concerning region.

(3) Show a list of businesses (details) belonging to a specific Category AND a specific Region

I have tried a number of things, but without success. If anyone could help me out, I'd be VERY happy.

Comment: You mind posting some snippets of what you **have** tried?

Answer (score 0):

Ad 1) What I've tried:

```
// show a list of categories for a region (taxonomy = "region")

<?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); ?>

<?php query_posts(array( 'post_type'=>'business', 'region'=>$term->slug)); ?>

<?php
if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) :
      the_post();
      the_category(' &raquo; ','multiple');
      echo '<br/>';
   endwhile;
endif;
?>

// but, how to show a category only once?
```

Ad 2) What I've tried: see ad 1) plus how to show parent category only?

Ad 3) What I've tried: see ad 1. Only, how to filter for a specific category?

Answer (score 0):

Plus, I've added the below to my functions.php:

```
// Add Business to the query

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
function query_post_type($query) {
  if(is_category() || is_tag()) {
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
    if($post_type)
        $post_type = $post_type;
    else
        $post_type = array('post','business','nav_menu_item');
    $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
    return $query;
    }
}
```